# CentOS: ulimit hard/soft limits keep reset to default values

Tags: linux, centos, ulimit

On `CentOS7` I am trying to change the values of `ulimit` as following:

```
ulimit -Hn 262144
ulimit -Sn 100000
```

But the value is being reset to its default values just after signing out:

```
[root@server001]# ulimit -Hn
4096
[root@server001]# ulimit -Sn
1024
```

Am I setting the values permanently this way? if not, how to do it?

And if it is permanent, why it is coming back to its default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set limits with the `ulimit` command, your changes will remain effective only until log out or reboot. It's the observed behavior.

To change limits permanently you have to edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Here is how to set the values for soft and hard number of open files for everyone (`*`).

```
*               soft    nofile          100000
*               hard    nofile          262144
```

For the changes to take effect you need to log out and re-login.

More info in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)